# How can I implement speech recognition in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

how to install speech_recognition module in python and how to convert voice command to string in python?

i'm already done it on my python 3.7 but i'm failed to do it

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Speak Anything :")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print(f"You said : {}".format(text))
    except Exception:
        print("Sorry could not recognize what you said")

print(f"You said : {}".format(text))
     ^
```

SyntaxError: f-string: empty expression not allowed

Answer (score 0):

F-strings expect you to actually specify a variable. Using the `.format()` method explicitly is something you do on regular strings, not f-strings. So either

```
print("You said : {}".format(text))
```

or

```
print(f"You said : {text}")
```

will work.

Comment: I did what you said but i got another error which is installing pyaudio module ?

Comment: That one, I'm not sure how to help you with. I'd advise making a new question, and listing there precisely what the error message you're getting is, and what you're doing to get it.